# Determine what process requested pinentry

Tags: linux, gnupg, gpg-agent

Is there a way to figure out **what process triggered [pinentry prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOBmo.png)**?

In other words, imagine the prompt pops up, and you have no idea why (what process, what action triggered it). How would you figure it out?

Another question is more general - what is signalling mechanism behind such dialogs (dbus? gpg unix socket? something else?).

P.S.

Unfortunately process tree does not help:

```
  ├─systemd,138622 --user
  │   ├─(sd-pam),138623
  │   ├─dbus-daemon,138647 --session --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
  │   ├─dconf-service,139188
  │   │   ├─{gdbus},139190
  │   │   └─{gmain},139189
  │   ├─gpg-agent,139317 --supervised
  │   │   ├─pinentry,139327 --display :0
  │   │   │   ├─{QDBusConnection},139349
  │   │   │   └─{QXcbEventQueue},139330
```

Comment: Is it possible to paste the whole process tree ?

Comment: Maybe bpftrace tools could help you debug the problem (https://www.brendangregg.com/ebpf.html). I'm thinking in particular of execsnoop which can trace new processes execution.